# llvm: create struct type array (pointer)

Tags: pointers, struct, llvm

I'm working with llvm (frontend: C++) and trying to implement the struct type array (struct type pointer) in my language. My struct looks like this:

```
  struct myStruct {
    double const *myArray; //double type array
    char const *myString; //string

  };
```

And my code for struct type array implementation:

```
...
auto myString = Type::getInt8PtrTy(TheContext);
auto myArray = Type::getDoublePtrTy(TheContext);
auto myStruct = StructType::create(TheContext, "Struct"); 
myStruct->setBody({myString, myArray}); 
return PointerType::get(myStruct, 0);
```

I think that this way isn't correct because when I'm assigning data to the pointer and trying to print the array elements I got only first struct array element and only "myString" ("myArray" is always empty). I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Additional code:

```
struct myStruct* getData(){
 

    double const arr1[3] = { 10, 7, 9 }; double const* arraypnt1 = arr1; char const *str1 = "string1";
     double const arr2[3] = { 1, 2, 4}; double const* arraypnt2 = arr2; char const *str2 = "string2";
    
     struct myStruct p[2] = {{ arraypnt1, str1 }, { arraypnt2, str2 }};
     struct myStruct* pairarr = p; // array of pairs
     return pairarr;

}
```

```
//code generator
Value *ASTVarExpression::generateCode() {

      Function *function = Builder.GetInsertBlock()->getParent();
      Value *initValue = VariableValue->generateCode(); //this line creates call to function 'getData()' 
      if (!initValue) { return nullptr; }
      
      AllocaInst *alloca = CreateFunctionEntryAlloca(function, VariableName, GetType(DeclaredType)); 
      Builder.CreateStore(initValue, alloca); //store 'getData()' result in variable which type is 'myStructure* '
    
      NamedValues[VariableName] = alloca;
      return initValue;

}
```

```
static AllocaInst *CreateFunctionEntryAlloca(Function *function, StringRef variableName, Type* variableType) {

      IRBuilder<> tempBlock(&function->getEntryBlock(), function->getEntryBlock().begin());
      return tempBlock.CreateAlloca(variableType, 0, variableName);

}
```

```
Type *GetType(int expressionType){ //returns struct array type

      auto myString = Type::getInt8PtrTy(TheContext);
      auto myArray = Type::getDoublePtrTy(TheContext);
      auto myStruct = StructType::create(TheContext, "Struct"); 
      myStruct->setBody({myString, myArray}); 
      return PointerType::get(myStruct, 0); 

}
```

```
llvm IR code:

      %varName = alloca %Struct.0*, align 8
      %gencall = call %Struct* @getData()
      store %Struct* %gencall, %Struct.0** %varName, align 8
      ret %Struct* %gencall
```

Comment: Looks sensible at first glance, except that do you really want your strings to be represented as a pointer to a 64-bit integer?

Comment: Can you add the additional code and output you get for the stuff which you found strange? The snippet you've posted only shows type construction, not value construction

Comment: Are you loading the array elements before printing them ??

Comment: @droptop yes, of course

Comment: could you add the llvm ir code that does so ??